# Any difference between vimdiff and vim -d?

Tags: vimdiff

Are there any differences between using `vimdiff x.py y.py` and `vim -d x.py y.py`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your vim supports diff mode (which is in most cases), there is no difference.

There is a minor difference though, if your vim is compiled without the `+diff` feature, `vimdiff a b` will produce the error message:

```
This Vim was not compiled with the diff feature.
```

However, `vim -d a b` will silently accept without entering diff mode.

Unless you are on amiga, in which case the `-d` is interpreted as a device name for use as a terminal.